# Unexpected current of ZVS circuit and transformer

Tags: current, transformer, zvs

I recently built a ZVS circuit to drive a step up transformer to charge some 1000uF 450V capacitors. The ZVS works fine and the capacitors charge to around 390V pretty quick. So I wanted to check the current at the output of the transformer to see if it matches what I expected. I used my multimeter in current mode to complete the circuit between the transformer and bridge rectifier and measured around 0.3A but this is far below what I expected. Here's the primary voltage with open circuit secondary.

[image]

So it works good with a 42V peak at 10kHz. And then unloaded secondary voltage is around 418V peaks so that gives a ratio of about 10. So if the secondary current is 0.3A then theres 3A in the primary. But during charging my power supply current limits to 10A. So I'm putting in 10A and only getting 3A of resonance? I was expecting more like 30A in the primary and have 3A on the secondary. I'm not sure why this is. Here's a picture of the ZVS circuit. [image]

Also, I'm using these UF4007 diodes in the bridge rectifier but I'm unsure if they're fast enough and they might be the problem? Thanks in advance

[image]

Update: I tried using smaller values for L1 and L3 at 1mH each to see if saturation was a problem but this increased the power supply current to 10A at no load on the secondary.

Comment: You really need to show a schematic.

Comment: I added a schematic

Comment: Is L2 the primary of your transformer?

Comment: Yes L2 is the primary

Comment: Your multimeter probably can't measure the current at the switching frequency. Check the specifications of the multimeter.

Comment: Ah jeez! You're right its way out of its range. Mine can handle 40Hz to 1kHz so that is probably the issue. I was just about to measure it through a shunt with my oscilloscope too. I'll see how the shunt goes but thank you I would've never thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Andy for making me realise my meter is unable to handle the 10 kHz switching frequency of my secondary output as seen in its [datasheet](https://btmco.ir/images/EditorUpload/VC97_manual.pdf).

Using a 6.8 Ω shunt in series with the 1000 μF capacitor and got this on the oscilloscope for the voltage across the resistor:

[image]

The peak voltage of 21.2 V means a peak current of around 3.1 A; much more reasonable. So without the shunt the current is what I expected which is great.